# Subtree definition

Tags: graph-theory, trees

The definition of **subtree** of a tree is a tree that descends from a node of the starting tree. My question is if we can consider the "cross tree" below and say that the graph starting from $A$, going to the **red node** and branching toward $C$ and $D$ is a subtree of the previous cross tree or if the only subtree is the one starting from the **red node**. I have some confusions about the definition of subtree. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything depends from what vertex is a **root**. Guess that exactly $A$ is a root and guess that **red vertex** is called $E$ $\implies$ $\text{subtrees}$={$CE$, $ED$, $CED$, $CEB$, $BED$, $AEC$, $AEB$, $AED$, $AECD$, $AEBD$, $AEBC$, $AEBCD$} are a subtrees of the presented tree by you.

Also I can provide other images describing a definition **subtree**:

[image]

or

[image]

or

[image]

Comment: So I cannot say that AECD is a subtree of the whole tree? what if I suppose both A and B are roots?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the precise definition of a tree.

If a tree is an unoriented, simple graph, which is connected and doesn't have loops, then a subtree is just a connected subgraph. In this case, the subgraph you describe is a subtree.

If a tree is an oriented, simple graph, such that the underlying unoriented graph is connected and doesn't have loops, and you define a subtree (associated to some vertex $x$) to be the set of vertices $y$ such that there exists a finite sequence of oriented arrows such that each starts where the one before ends, such that the first one begins at $x$, and the last ends at $y$, then whether the subgraph you describe is a subtree or not depends on the orientation you choose on the edges.

There are also definitions of rooted trees: these are trees with a distinguished vertex. There are probably definitions of subtrees in rooted trees that specify the subtree to share the root with the tree... I don't know really.

In conclusion, you check the precise definition of the words "tree" and "subtree" in the reference you are using.

Comment: Thank you! So in my case, considering your second paragraph, if I consider the cross tree to be oriented “downward”, that is from A to the red node and from B to the red node, and from the red node to C and D, can I say that the subgraph AE and the edges C and D is a su tree of my oriented tree?

Comment: But I am considering AECD as subtree

Comment: Thank you! Vadim

Comment: Last thing and I accept the answer: would this imply that ABEC or ABED are not subtrees of the starting one?

Comment: my mistake i think. I accept your answer

Comment: Lol I think you discussed in the comments section of the wrong answer, and have therefore accepted mine as a valid answer :D